# Vuforia Extended Tracking - Is it able to keep a whole scene to look around or is it only meant for one object?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Our goal is to track a target once and then have a scene be built that you can turn around and look at, without the objects moving too much (most basic example is just 6 spheres distributed over 360° around you).
Extended Tracking seems to be the tool for the job, but out of the box it is kind of unstable and shaky, and loses positions quickly when turning away from the marker/target.

Is there any approach (I'm thinking script-wise) to build upon the standard behavior and make it more robust, **e.g. retain the objects at the place they were scanned first**?

Comment: I think Extended Tracking is exactly this, and would guess that there is no way to make it better yourself. The quality depends on the environment and especially the device: which sensors it has, ARCore or ARKit support maybe, and how well Vuforia can use those. https://library.vuforia.com/features/environments/device-tracker-overview.html

Comment: @antont Yeah after all that we ended up using the standard implmentation, since that seemed to be the one working the best (even though still pretty unstable)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Image Targets to track image, then make the following changes in the script > DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs

```
protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
{
  ....
  ....
  StartCoroutine(TurnOffTracking());
}

IEnumerator TurnOffTracking()
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(2); //Keeping a delay of 2 seconds after the image has been tracked

  TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop(); //Tracking will be stopped and the objects that have been positioned after getting tracked will be in the same position in world space
}
```

Make sure you do the following changes in the project:
(a) Extended tracking (device position tracker) is enabled.
(b) Set world center mode of Vuforia Behaviour in AR camera to "DEVICE".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried it (with the points you mention in a* and b*) but unfortunately this did not really work. It only made it slightly more buggy looking. I think turning it off completely only hinders the stabilization process of the camera.

Comment: I have been doing this for many vuforia projects. It works fine with me with no jitter at all. Could you post screenshot of AR camera?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you try a mashup of two different components. Firstly you could use a normal target detection for the image. Then after you catch the event that the image was recognised, you would simply activate the Ground plane tracking (you can just prompt the user to look down and then tap or something similar).

The reason extended tracking doesn't work so well for you is that it is not designed to cary space tracking on its own it only remembers the image position roughly in its FOV so that different obstructions don't cause tracking issues.

Hope this helped clarify it a bit!

Comment: Can you give me any direction on how I could combine these two code-wise? As I can see, both the `ImageTarget` and the `PlaneFinder` use the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`, so it is one script and I can't seem to figure out how to differentiate which one is triggering it.

Comment: I don't think this is true actually - the docs say that e.g. ground plane tracking depends on the device tracking, and that they use all available means to do the device tracking which also extended tracking then uses: "While other trackers track images or objects, this tracker uses visual details of the environment in the camera view as well as, in some cases, the built-in inertial measurement unit (IMU) sensor to determine the six-degree-of-freedom pose of the device itself" https://library.vuforia.com/features/environments/device-tracker-overview.html